# How to combine multiple sites to Wordpress MU

Tags: multisite

I have multiple well-established Wordpress sites.

I am considering combining them into one Wordpress MU site. I have found that a few of the sites probably do not get as much of my attention as they should. I think this may simply be because they are "out of sight, out of mind." I believe with all sites in one dashboard, they will get much more attention.

Is this the way to go? What is the best method to combine the sites? I haven't been able to find a tutorial or really too much information.

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to attain more exposure, your energy would be much better invested in promoting them (cross-site linking, SEO, adwords etc.) than simply merging them into one install (for which I doubt you'll see little gain, other than a network that is easier to manage).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Exposure isn't the issue. I am happy with the traffic generated by each site. Some of the sites simply don't need constant updates and don't have blogs, but I find that I don't visit myself often. I think combining all the sites into a MU installation may force my attention a little more, resulting in even better performance.

Comment: Ahh, completely misread your intent with "attention" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Manually

I'm pretty sure I've seen this topic covered by [Ipstenu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/7886/ipstenu) and/or [Andrea](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/1391/andrea-r) in Multisite [support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/multisite). But this demands a in-depth search in the **un-friendly** search functionality of WordPress.org.

And if my memory serves me well, I think the solution is to *invert* the method used to ***extract*** a site from Multisite.

This method is described in the 12th chapter of the book [WORDPRESS MULTISITE 101](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/), by Mika Epstein (aka Ipstenu).

She has another one that's **quite worth** reading as well: [WORDPRESS MULTISITE 110](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-110/), in partnership with Andrea Rennick.

Don't forget to tip the jar if you find them useful :). Well, they **are really useful** :)))

### Automated

I think there are other plugins that do it as well, but am not sure...

The solution I use is a *paid* one: [BackupBuddy](http://pluginbuddy.com/purchase/backupbuddy/). It allows ***extracting***/***injecting*** sites from/to a Multisite in a breeze.

If you follow this path, my suggestion is to:

- export the Single site
- import the backup file into a new Multisite installation
- check that is all working in the basic *folder* or *subdomain* address
- map the domain to this new Multisite site (in the cPanel and in the [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/))
- you still will have the original WordPress installation files residing in your server and its database data (case something goes wrong, simply un-map the domain in the plugin and map it to the old folder in the cPanel)

### Alternative

Use [InfiniteWP](http://infinitewp.com/features/). It is like [ManageWP](https://managewp.com/), but free.

With it you access all your sites dashboards (Single or Multisite sites) in one single interface. And if you excuse a little excess, it is ***damn cool*** !

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is *probably* going to be the Import/Export tools. Export each individual site into WXR files, then import into your MultiSite install. I'm assuming you'll also need to set up a [MultiSite domain mapping plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

See Otto's article about [how to set up the domain mapping](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-multisite-domain-mapping-tutorial/) (but ignore the remarks about 3.0 compatibility, because the plugin has been updated since the time Otto wrote the article).